# Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR - assumed '_DIR_'

Tags: php

I am getting this error. Cant seem to find what the problem is:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DIR - assumed '*DIR*' in C:\wamp\www\Authentication\app\start.php on line 7

How can I get rid of this error?

Here is the code:

```
    <?php
    session_cache_limiter(false);
    session_start();
    define('INC_ROOT', dirname(_DIR_));
    echo INC_ROOT;
    ?>
```

I also tried `dirname(_FILE_)` and it still doesn't work. I'm using php 5.5.12

Comment: *"Can someone help me please?"* - sure, maybe... got some code to boot?

Comment: <?php
session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();
define('INC_ROOT', dirname(_DIR_));
echo INC_ROOT;
?>

Comment: ok, you didn't indent your code; failed a new line.

Comment: the syntax is `__DIR__` RTM  http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php with 2x underscores on both sides.

Comment: I'm putting the two underscores at each side but its not sending in the code...but yes i do have the two underscores in my code

Comment: your question's code contained `_DIR_` when I edited your question. If it does read as `__DIR__` then edit your question. same for `__FILE__` you only have 1x on each side. *"I also tried `dirname(_FILE_)`"*

Comment: Oh wow! It works. Thanks alot. It's my first time using this site and the response was much faster than what i expected. This is my new home. Thanks alot! I really appreciate it. Are the people here always this helpful?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ so you can see and learn how to ask a good question here on SO. Also you can take a tour here: [tour] to get a quick overview.

Comment: what do you mean it works? what did I miss here? *"I'm putting the two underscores at each side but its not sending in the code...but yes i do have the two underscores in my code"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- [It's magic](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/22032391.jpg) :)

Comment: @Rizier123 [You're telling me...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11A8JZ-RDDo). No idea what I should do here and if OP knows what to do. *Baffled*.

Comment: Sorry about that...I phrased that wrong. i had two underscores - one at each side

Comment: @Dan180 You can always [edit] your question and improve it!

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks i realize. I'm going to do my best to get use to the site and make sure my questions are properly constructed next time

Comment: *"Are the people here always this helpful?"* - Indeed Dan. We like to work fast, don't we @Rizier123 ? RR ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes we do, *Ralph*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"i had two underscores - one at each side"*

As per the manual

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

The magic constants require 2X underscores on **both** sides.

- `__DIR__`
- `__FILE__`